# how to convert avi file to yuv 420 (software/matlab/source code/c/c++ anything)

Tags: matlab, avi, yuv

Guys I want to convert an avi file into yuv 420 video clip. Is there any method to do that? thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read an AVI file into MATLAB [using the built-in `mmreader` class](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-132080.html#f5-146610). Once you have the AVI frames read into a structure array of movie frames, you can save them as a YUV file using the `saveFileYuv` function found in this submission from the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/):

- [Convert YUV CIF 4:2:0 video file to image files](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6318-convert-yuv-cif-420-video-file-to-image-files) by [Da Yu](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/16240)

Your code might look something like this:

```
%# Get the video data:

vidObj = mmreader('myVideo.avi');  %# Create a video file object
nFrames = vidObj.NumberOfFrames;   %# Get the number of frames
vidHeight = vidObj.Height;         %# Get the image height
vidWidth = vidObj.Width;           %# Get the image width

%# Preallocate the structure array of movie frames:

mov(1:nFrames) = struct('cdata',zeros(vidHeight,vidWidth,3,'uint8'),...
                        'colormap',[]);  %# Note that colormap is empty!

%# Read each video frame into the structure array:

for k = 1:nFrames
  mov(k).cdata = read(vidObj,k);  %# Place frame k in the cdata field of mov(k)
end

%# Save the movie frame array as a YUV 4:2:0 file:

saveFileYuv(mov,'myVideo.yuv',1);
```

Comment: hi gnovice. I followed your suggestion and call the two functions. I got some problem with the colormap. How do i specify each mov(k).colormap? thx

Comment: @yoursclark: I updated my answer with some sample code. You shouldn't have to specify anything for the `colormap` field (i.e. just make it the empty matrix `[]`) since the frames you will place in the `cdata` field will be RGB (e.g. [truecolor](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-12468)) images.

Comment: Thank you very much gnovice. your explanation is very clear and helpful!thx!

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using Matlab. What you want to do can easily be done using mplayer/mencoder... Why use Matlab for that ?

mencoder.exe -of rawvideo clock.avi -o clock.yuv -nosound -ovc raw

You may add -vf swapuv to swap the U and V components if the colrs aren't correct.